# How can i install manage package into professional edition account

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, managed-package, static-resources, professional-edition

I am unable to install manage package into professional edition account and got error [image]

I need steps and guide lines to install package.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This edition does not support Apex.

The only way to get Apex into a Professional Edition is to have a managed package that has passed security review on AppExchange.